# LiveValidation submits form without validating other fields if Select2 field is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, jquery-select2

I'm using **LiveValidation** for client side form validation. *http://livevalidation.com/examples*

I also have a multiselect form field that has **Select2** applied to it.

Problem is, if I leave that **Select2** field empty (*not choose anything*) then my form will submit itself after pressing Submit button, without validating any other form fields.

But if I do select something in the **Select2** field and try to submit the form then **LiveValidation** will try to validate other fields (*including the **Select2** field*) in the form and if they fail validation - the form doesn't submit and prompts the user to fix the errors first.

**Update:** Even if I remove the Select2 from my multiselect form field the LiveValidation still skips validation when it's left empty / nothing is selected.

---

The select field with **Select2** applied (*I populate the select's options with values of rows from a single column in a table using PHP function getSelectOptions*):

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" method="post" action="myscript.php">
...
<select id="myselect" name="myselect[]" multiple="multiple">
    <?php getSelectOptions("table_name", "column_name"); ?>
</select>
...
</form>
```

Here's how I apply **Select2** to that select field earlier in the file:

```
$(function()
{
...
$('#myselect').select2({ placeholder: "Select items" });
...
});
```

And here I apply the **LiveValidation** to the select field after **Select2** (*By adding **Validate.Presence** I'm telling it that the select field mustn't be empty / is required to have a value*):

```
$(function()
{
...
var myselect = new LiveValidation("myselect", { onlyOnSubmit: true });          
myselect.add(Validate.Presence);
...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" value="Your Name" name="name" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value        = 'Your Name';}"  onfocus="if (this.value == 'Your Name') {this.value = '';}" />
```

Replace 'Your Name' with something that fits your situation. if the user does not fill in this field it will revert to that value and fail

Oh i misunderstood, so to clarify instead of using onlyonSubmite:true...would adding an ifelse work.

```
 if(!myselect) {
      throw error
  else { 
    //do what you need
   }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: My text inputs work fine. It's the `<select>` that doedn't properly validate when left empty.

Answer (score 0):

I would add this as a comment, but I don't have the rep yet. Still, I have exactly the same problem using select2 with Ruby On Rails: i.e. if the field is left empty (it's a multi-select in my case as well), the other validations are skipped, BOTH client-side (I'm using Client Side Validations), AND server-side (AJAX response).

However, as in your case, if there is a selection in the select2 field, all the other validations fire fine.

My (ugly) workaround was to cherry-pick the empty select2 field on the create action server-side and return the error to the modal (where my form lives) via AJAX. This at least avoids the nasty 500 error I was getting in the console. For the sake of completeness, and anybody else running into this in ROR-land, the hack code looks like this:

```
 def create
  # messaged is params definition of field contents
  if messaged.blank?
   #create a dummy message instance
    @message = Message.new
   #add error and call the whole thing off
    @message.errors.add(:base, "No recipients selected.")
    return
  end
  #rest of the normal action...
 end
```

And here's the modal JS:

```
var el = $('#new-message-form');

<% if @message.errors.any? %>

  // Create a list of errors
  var errors = $('<ul />');

  <% @message.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>
    errors.append('<li><%= escape_javascript( error ) %></li>');
  <% end %>

  // Display errors on form

  $('.modalerrors').html(errors).show('slideDown');
  $('.modalerrors').delay(5000).hide('slideUp');



<% else %>

    $('#messageModal').modal('hide');

    // hide then Clear form and reload page

    $('#messageModal').on('hidden', function () {
        el.find('input:text,textarea').val('');
        el.find('.modalerrors').empty();
       <% @message = "" %>
        location.reload();
    });
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps someone. Or better yet, leads to a fix.